# OpenDJ Multi-master replication fails(Hangs at Initializing registration information step):: javax.naming.AuthenticationException

Tags: replication, opendj, multi-master-replication

I am using OpenDJ-2.4.6 along with Oracle JDK 7.80 and I want to run Multi-master replication on 2 of my servers, the OS for these servers is Amazon Linux.

The OpenDJ setup runs perfectly fine; I can start the server too without any errors.

It is when I run the "**dsreplication**" script as follows:

**`./dsreplication enable --host1 server1.example,com --port1 4444 --bindDN1 "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword1 "Passw0rd" --replicationPort1 1388 --host2 server2.example,com --port2 4444 --bindDN2 "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword2 "Passw0rd" --replicationPort2 1388 --adminUID admin --adminPassword "Passw0rd" --baseDN "dc=example,dc=com"`**

the script hangs on the following step:

```
Initializing registration information on server server2.example.com:4444 with the contents of server server1.example.com:4444 .....
```

And on checking the logs, there is no error reported in there.

But, when I run the following command:

```
./dsreplication status -h localhost -p 4444 --adminUID admin --adminPassword "Passw0rd" -X
```

it throws the following error:

> The displayed information might not be complete because the following
>   errors were encountered reading the configuration of the existing
>   servers: Error on server2.example.com:4444: An error occurred
>   connecting to the server.  Details:
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid
>   Credentials] Error on server:4444: An error occurred connecting to the
>   server. Details: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error
>   code 49 - Invalid Credentials]

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error could not be more explicit: "Invalid Credentials" on server 2.

Check the bindDN and bindPassword are valid against server 2.

Comment: all my passwords are same, even across the servers, so this definitely shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

When doing replication with OpenDJ, the hostnames must be resolved and addressable from either machines. Have you checked that this is the case with your Amazon Linux servers ?